# Making MovieClip clickable with MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Using ActionScript 3.0, Im trying to make several MoveClips clickable. I'm using a loop to generate a clip in an array.

```
var mc:MovieClip = new Brett();
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
tblBrett[i] = addChild(mc);
```

No errors, but the "muj" object isnt moving as wanted. I don't think the function is running at all:

```
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
muj.x = 500;
}
```

Everything is working, except that nothing is happening when I'm clicking the movie clips.

Comment: I haven't seen making an Array position equal an addChild before, that's not to say it doesn't do something (I don;'t know I've never tried it) but if you just want a reference to mc within the array you would just tblBrett[i] = mc;. Apart from that the handler and listener both look right

Comment: When using tblBrett[i] = mc the MovieClips is not generated at all, but it works with addChild. Though not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, by adding the listener in a separate loop.

```
 for (i = 0; i < 42; i++) 
{ 
    tblBrett[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, flyttFigur);
}

function flyttFigur(event:MouseEvent)
{
     muj.x = event.currentTarget.x;
     muj.y = event.currentTarget.y;

}
```